# Are Schwarzenegger libraries fact or fiction?

Tags: demolition-man

Are there any real Schwarzenegger libraries today? In the movie "Demolition Man" there was an actual Schwarzenegger library after "President Schwarzenegger".

So is it fact or pure fiction?

Comment: is....is this a serious question? or are you trolling?

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional: Some men just want to see their rep burn.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are obviously no Schwarzenegger libraries in the sense that the movie meant it. It was referring to a [*presidential* library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presidential_library), like the Clinton library in Little Rock, Arkansas or the Reagan Library in Simi Valley, California. Presidential libraries aren't like public libraries you're familiar with. They don't have stacks or card catalogs or even many books. Rather, they have archives of (often still classified) material from the president's administration and personal lives. Researchers are able to access some of this material with permission. They usually also have a section that's a museum and open to the public.

Sadly, there also [don't appear to be any public libraries](https://www.google.com/search?q=schwarzenegger+site%3Apubliclibraries.com) in the United States that are either named after Arnold or coincidentally named after a person with the same last name. It's possible that Austria has a library with the name, as it's more common there, although none appear on the German language Wikipedia's [list of libraries in Austria](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bibliotheken_in_%C3%96sterreich).

In fact, the only building I can find that carried the name was the [UPC-Arena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPC-Arena) in Graz, Austria (near where he was born). It was called the Arnold Schwarzenegger Arena from 2000 to 2005.

Comment: +1 for answering this with a "straight face".